# How do I set up SSL in zend server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, zend-server-ce

I have a clean install of Zend Server CE, and I've been trying to add SSL support for the past hours, but I have no idea how, I moved the same SSL configuration file from xampp to zend (changed the directives and added the ssl keys and certificates, ofcourse), and mixed and matched all the configurations (because on xampp it worked), and now I'm getting "Forbidden" whenever I try to access through https.

ssl config:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>

Listen 443

<IfModule mime_module>

    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
</IfModule>

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin


SSLMutex default


<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2"
    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>


    SSLEngine on


    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL


    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"


    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"


    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>


    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


    CustomLog "logs/ssl_request.log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>                                  

</IfModule>
```

httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2"
Listen  80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>

User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@example.com

DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig conf/mime.types


    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

</IfModule>

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf
# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
Include "conf/zend.conf"
#ZEND-{3DD6CFEC510EAE9CB9951C5099C97701}
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
#ZEND-{7E9DA216F3BFDA8C024B94938291EBEC}
Include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer/etc/sites.d/zend-default-vhost-80.conf"
#ZEND-{7E9DA216F3BFDA8C024B94938291EBEC}
</VirtualHost>
#ZEND-{3DD6CFEC510EAE9CB9951C5099C97701}
#ZEND-{AFAB3E9707435D6B0888B566D7AD3FF8}
Include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer/etc/sites.d/globals-*.conf"
Include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer/etc/sites.d/vhost_*.conf"
#ZEND-{AFAB3E9707435D6B0888B566D7AD3FF8}
```